# I have an input box and would like the dollar sign to position depending on the input

Tags: html, css

Here is the block of code in HTML and CSS

```css
.Container {
  position: relative;
}

.Dollarsign {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
  text-align:center;
}

.Input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='Container'>
  <div class='Input '>
    <div class='Dollarsign'>$</div>
    20213</div>
</div>
```

I would like the dollar sign to be right next to the numbers and adjusts position if the number increases or decreases.

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate (join) the 2 strings like `string = Number + " $" ` ? They will always be together wherever you place the number.

Comment: Because I am trying to have different fonts for each one @MohsenAlyafei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.BetCalculator__Bet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .BetCalculator__Input-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .BetCalculator__Bet-dollarsign {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: green;
    border:solid;
    text-align:center;
  }
  
  .BetCalculator__Bet-input {
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    border:solid;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class='BetCalculator__Input-container'>
    <div class='BetCalculator__Bet-input'>
      <div class='BetCalculator__Bet-dollarsign'>$</div>
      <div>202143434343</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ZiyadMorsi Approve it as the answer so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `after` for better experience:

```css
.dollar:after {
  content: '$';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.euro:after {
  content: '€';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="dollar">1000</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 class="euro">1000</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo will also do the job :

```css
.Input:before {
  content: '$';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
  /* optionnal / eventually */
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: 0.4em;
}

.Input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='Container'>
  <div class='Input '>
    20213</div>
</div>
```

You may also use different currency via the lang attribute value.

```css
.Input:before {
  content: '$';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
  /* optionnal / eventually */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 0.4em;
}

.Input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

[lang="fr"] {
  color: blue
}

.Input[lang="fr"]:before {
  content: '€';
  color: crimson
}
```

```html
<div class='Container' lang="us">
  <div class='Input '>
    20213</div>
</div>


<div class='Container'>
  <div class='Input ' lang="fr">
    3072020</div>
</div>
```